# jQuery Validation plugin validating form on button click

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

So I have a seven part form where six tabs are hidden via CSS and when a user clicks next another part fades in.

I've submitted the page to make sure the plugin is working; it is.
Essentially its just going to the next part of the form without validation the current part

As an example

HTML

```
<form id = "form1" action = "backend.php" method = "post">
<label for "phone">First Name </label>
    <input type = "text" name = "fName" placeholder = "First Name..." class = "required" id = "fName" />
<button id = "btn" type = "button" class = "buttonnav next">next</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('#btn').click( function() { $("#form1").validate();});
```

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Validate plugin?  That would be something to mention.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using [the jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin, with your code, the plugin is not initialized until after the button is clicked.  If the plugin is not initialized, then there's no validation.

```
$('#btn').click( function() { $("#form1").validate();});
```

Instead, [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) gets called once on DOM ready to *initialize* the plugin on the form.

If you want to *test* the form at any time after initialization, you would use the [`.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize plugin
        // your options
    });

    $('#btn').click( function() { 
        $("#form1").valid();  // test the form for validity
    });

});
```

---

I have no idea how you've set up each part to to interact with each other or what other code is being used.  Based on your OP alone, here is a working example using my answer above.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pqVJM/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').validate();

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        if ($("#form1").valid()) {
            alert('hello - valid form');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using the validation plugin. I edited my script to this; unfortunately I'm still getting the same result as before.  Dont know if this helps or not(or shows my ignorance...), I tried if ($("#form1").valid() == true){alert("hello");} inside the click handler to see if anything was going through, and was getting constant "hello"

Comment: @ArtTaylor, I have no idea where else you're going wrong... you have not shown enough code in your OP.

Comment: @ArtTaylor, See my edited answer.  With my answer applied, your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/pqVJM/

Comment: Thank you for your input,  I got it this morning. I really appreciate the help guys.